# Multiple values for argument in method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, typeerror

I always get this error when running:

```
TypeError: request() got multiple values for argument 'query'
```

I looked into several «similar» issues on stackoverflow but nothing helped. any hit would be highly appreciated.

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class myClass:
  def __init__(self):
    return;

  def functionXYZ(var):
    return;

  def request(query=''):
    xyz = self.functionXYZ(var=query);
    return xyz;

conn = myClass();
qry = 'SOME STRING';
res = conn.request(query=qry);
print(res);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're bitten by the fact you haven't added `self` to the methods of your class.

Method calls pass the instance, *implicitly*, as a first argument, that is, what your call to `request` is doing is:

1. passing `self`, implicitly, as the value of `query`
2. passing `query` a second time with `query=qry`.

Add `self` to your method or, if you don't need the instance, make them `staticmethod`s. Also, using `pass` instead of `return;` is always better (and `;` isn't required).